# getting filename attribute twice in content-disposition

Tags: .net-core, content-disposition

I am returning a file from my dotnet core api-controller like below

```
return File(csvData, "text/csv", "file.csv");
```

and in the browser response, what I get is

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv; filename*=UTF-8''file.csv
```

Why is the `filename` attribute coming twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two attributes, "filename" and "filename*".

See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html.